# Pythonic way of writing function

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api

I am new to python and writing a function to generate coordinates. Can any one please explain , what is right way to rewrite the function efficiently in pythonic way.

```
def generate_lat_long(location):
    coordinates = {}
    coordinates_blank = {"latitude": None,
                         "longitude": None}
    if location:
        geolocator = GoogleV3(botsetting.GOOGLE_API_KEY)
        location_raw = geolocator.geocode(location, language='en')
        if location_raw:
            coordinates['latitude'] = location_raw.latitude
            coordinates['longitude'] = location_raw.longitude

            print("printing coordinated from google ap1", coordinates)
            return coordinates
        else:
            return coordinates_blank

    else:

        return coordinates_blank
```

apart from that I am getting the following exception

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/embed/PycharmProjects/slack_grocerbot/BotUtils.py", line 31, in <module>
    generate_lat_long('kolkata')
  File "/home/embed/PycharmProjects/slack_grocerbot/BotUtils.py", line 15, in generate_lat_long
    latitude = location.latitude
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

Thanks

Comment: For starters, indent your code. Indentation is important in Python.

Comment: You're missing a Google API tag I think

Comment: If your code works - this is a type of question better asked on codereview. If it doesn't - please tell us what is wrong with it :)

Comment: i will update my question

Comment: To be honest, I would use a class/named tuple to implement this. This is especially true if you want to do other operations with your coordinates later on (like calculating vectors between coordinates, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should avoid using `dict` if your only intend was returning multiple values. Just return `tuple` of two values:

```
from typing import Tuple, Optional


def generate_lat_long(location: str) -> Tuple[Optional[float], Optional[float]]:
    coordinates_blank = (None, None)

    if not location:
        return coordinates_blank

    geolocator = GoogleV3(botsetting.GOOGLE_API_KEY)
    location_raw = geolocator.geocode(location, language='en')

    if not location_raw:
        return coordinates_blank

    print("printing coordinated from google ap1", coordinates)
    return (location_raw.latitude, location_raw.longitude)
```

And then outside the function use it like this:

```
lat, lon = generate_lat_long('some place')
```

Also you can use type hints (this optional things like `location: str`, `-> Tuple[...]`) to annotate what your function expects to get and what it will return.